# Why NodeJS server return empty template?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'am trying to create React application with server side rendering friendly for Google search engine. As documentation says, I created simple NodeJS server, which is render React component to string, gets `index.html` template and replace root tag with rendered string. Everything is good if I open page from browser, but when I see page source there is only root tag exist (also `index.html` has same source), for example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="application"></div>
        <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

NodeJS server

```
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import express from 'express';

import React from 'react';
import { renderToString, } from 'react-dom/server';

import Application from './../components/application';

const appx  = express();
const port  = process.env.PORT || 8080;

const publicPath    = express.static(path.join(__dirname, './../'));
const indexPath     = path.join(__dirname, './../index.html');

appx.use(publicPath);
appx.get('*', (request, response) => {

    const reactDOM = renderToString(<Application/>);

    fs.readFile(indexPath, 'utf8', function (error, content) {

        if (error) {

            return response.status(500).send('Oops!');
        }

        let html = content.replace(`<div id="application"></div>`, `<div id="application">${reactDOM}</div>`);

        return response.status(200).send(html);
    });
});

appx.listen(port);
```

Why NodeJS is not send actual content?

PS. If add `console.log(html)` to server code before `return response.status(200).send(html);` it show message

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="application"><div data-reactroot=""><p>React server side rendering</p></div></div>
        <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest that you use the next.js framework to accomplish this task. They have made an amazing framework to solve the complications of server side rendering with react and they have great documentation. This is the go to way to do server side rendering in react. [Nextjs Link](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/getting-started)

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I want to understand why my script is work incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the exact reason without checking the whole source code. But one thing hasn't been mentioned in your description may be worth to check:

Do you use `ReactDOM.hydrate` in your client side JS at all? we are using that to make sure the React Components can be rendered properly (attach event listener etc).

Check this out: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#hydrate.